# Citing twice, results in two footnotes

Tags: footnotes, citing

when I cite an author twice, his name is also two times in the footnote.

My text:

```
Zum anderen können mit Hilfe dieser Systeme existierende 
unstrukturierte, qualitative Inhalte in BI-Analysen einbezogen 
werden und sie somit inhaltlich anreichern."'\footcite[S.12 u. 13]{RefWorks:150}\\
In der obersten Schicht, dem Informationszugriff werden Benutzerschnittstellen
bereitgestellt, um die steuerungsrelevanten Informationen abrufen zu können. 
Der Zugriff erfolgt in der Regel über Portale, die dem Benutzer als Einstiegspunkt 
für verschiedene Analysesysteme dienen.\footcite[S.12 u. 13]{RefWorks:150}
```

Results in:

[image]

Is it possible that latex is automatically recognizing that I'm citing that reference the second time and it's not creating a new footnote with the same entry? Instead latex is referencing the footnote that is already there? In this case 111.

Thanks and greets!

Comment: Hi and welcome, with the amount of information given, it is impossible to give any good advice due to the amount of possibilities that might have lead to the output. Please [provide us with testable and reproducable code](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/html/).

Comment: ***DO NOT USE DOUBLE BACKSLASH TO GET A BLANK LINE IN THE OUTPUT***

Comment: Using package `biblatex` along with the `ibidem` Tracker should get you quite a good starting point. https://github.com/johannesbottcher/HinweiseLitverzeichnisse

Comment: is \newline the proper way to get a blank line?

Comment: No. You want to have a blank line between paragraphs, right? How to get this depends on the class in use, which is not shown. http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/113/wie-erhalte-ich-eine-leerzeile-zwischen-absatzen

Comment: So far, you haven't got any feedback on the real issue here. Are there news? Can you provide a minimal working example?

Answer (score 2):

Package [opcit](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/opcit) does just this (among other things).

Comment: The usage of `\footcite` in the question seems to indicate `biblatex`.